# error: cannot find symbol class DataBindingComponent, Build okay but run failed

Tags: android, data-binding, compilation

[image]

I am facing a strange issue. I added QuickBlox SDK into an existing project where `DataBinding` was added and it worked properly.

After adding the QuickBlox SDK, I encountered the `DataBinding` issue at build time. Then I upgraded the Android studio to 3.2 Beta and got the build process successful. Now it is showing following error (screenshot) after pressing the RUN command.

I followed every possible method like Invalidate/restart the AS, changed Gradle plugin version from `2.1.3` to `3.1.3` and still no luck. Would be helpful to get the solution from someone.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Thu Jul 12 07:16:35 BDT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: I have these error when i have some issue in binding in layouts. Check all the layouts if there is some run-time error (red highlights).

Comment: I face same issue over time when using AS 3.1 . Don't know the reason . Invalidate cache and restart should work in some cases .

Comment: No luck yet. Checked layouts and no red highlights.

Comment: AS seems unable to perform the right errors when databinding fails. The root of the problem is elsewhere as I'd figured in such cases. But refering back was my only option..